# How to properly pass on an environment variable to Sun Grid Engine?

Tags: bash, sungridengine

I'm trying to submit a (series of) jobs to SGE (FWIW, it's a sequence of Gromacs molecular dynamics simulations), in which all the jobs are identical except for a suffix, such as `input01`, `input02`, etc. I wrote the commands to run in a way that the suffix is properly handled by the sequence of commands.

However, I can't find a way to get the exec environment to receive that variable. According to the `qsub` man page, `-v var` should do it.

```
$ export i=19
$ export | grep ' i='
declare -x i="19"
$ env | grep '^i='
i=19
```

Then, I submit the following script (`run.sh`) to see if it's received:

```
if [ "x" == "x$i" ]; then
    echo "ERROR: \$i not set"
else
    echo "SUCCESS: \$i is set"
fi
```

I submit the job as follows (in the same session as the `export` command above):

```
$ qsub -N "test_env" -cwd -v i run.sh
Your job 4606 ("test_env") has been submitted
```

The error stream is empty, and the output stream has:

```
$ cat test_env.o4606 
ERROR: $i not set
```

I also tried the following commands, unsuccessfully:

```
$ qsub -N "test_env" -cwd -v i -V run.sh
$ qsub -N "test_env" -cwd -V run.sh
$ qsub -N "test_env" -cwd -v i=19 -V run.sh
$ qsub -N "test_env" -cwd -v i=19 run.sh
```

If I add a line `i=19` to the beginning of `run.sh`, then the output is:

```
$ cat test_env.o4613
SUCCESS: $i is set as 19
```

I'm now considering generating a single file per job, which will essentially be the same but will have an `i=xx` line as the first. It doesn't look very much practical, but it would be a solution.

Would there be a better solution?

Comment: `qsub -N "test_env" -cwd -v="$i" run.sh` should work just fine.

Answer (score 7):

What I've been always doing is the following:

```
##send.sh
export a=10
qsub ./run.sh
```

and the script run.sh:

```
##run.sh
#$ -V
echo $a
```

when I call send.sh, the .o has an output of 10.

Comment: Thanks.  This involves the least extra typing, and does work even when the .sh script then calls another program (tested with R).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your variable is just an incrementing counter: You can use [Array Jobs](https://wiki.duke.edu/display/SCSC/SGE+Array+Jobs) to achieve this. This will set an `$SGE_TASK_ID` environment variable to the count which you can then copy to `$i` or use directly.

If the variable is anything else, then I think you'll have to generate multiple job scripts and submit each; that's the "solution" I use when I have loads of jobs with differing parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain you can pass variables by their name through qsub.  I've had success with passing values (you should probably write a front-end script for this instead of doing it interactively):

```
$ export ii=19
$ qsub -N "test_env" -cwd -v i=$ii run.sh
```